# Using index notation to show these equations are equal

Tags: vector-analysis, index-notation

> $$({\bf a}\times {\bf b})\cdot ({\bf a}\times {\bf b}) = |{\bf a}|^2|{\bf b}|^2 - ({\bf a}\cdot {\bf b})$$

I am doing the question above am stuck pretty much at the beginning. Any help? Thanks!

Comment: You know how to do cross product using the determinant of a matrix?

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**:

Call ${\bf a} = a_i{\bf e}_i$, and ${\bf b}=b_j{\bf e}_j$ and remember that

$$
{\bf a}\times {\bf b} = {\bf e}_i\epsilon_{ijk}a_jb_k
$$

You may also want to use the expression

$$
\epsilon_{ijk}\epsilon_{mnk} = \delta_{im}\delta_{jn}-\delta_{in}\delta_{jm}
$$